# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException from SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been struggling a while with querying my SQLite database using one of my table field. I successfully query using the `ForeignId` field, but not with the `Available` field of my table `QuizTable`. I was hoping you could point out something I missed. Here is the call I make to the function `queryQuiz`. Please note the `whereClause` (kind of cut off) which is supposed to filter the `available` field for a value of `1`. (side note: what if you want to query for different data types?)

```
QuizCursorWrapper cursor = db.queryQuiz(QuizTable.Cols.AVAILABLE + "=?", new String[]{"1"});
```

This is my queryQuiz function  in a class that extends `SQLiteOpenHelper`. 
Here's the error I am getting from calling `queryQuiz`: 
`Caused by: android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0`

```
public QuizCursorWrapper queryQuiz(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs){
    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            QuizTable.NAME,
            null,
            whereClause,
            whereArgs,
            null,
            null,
            null
    );
    return new QuizCursorWrapper(cursor);
}
```

my `QuizCursorWrapper` class

```
public class QuizCursorWrapper extends CursorWrapper {
    public QuizCursorWrapper(Cursor cursor){
        super(cursor);
    }

    public String getQuiz(){
        String paragraph = getString(getColumnIndex(QuizSchema.QuizTable.Cols.PARAGRAPH));
        return paragraph;
    }
    public String getQuizUUID(){
        String uuid = getString(getColumnIndex(QuizSchema.QuizTable.Cols.UUID));
        return uuid;
    }
}
```

and finally, my `QuizSchema` which defines the fields in my table.

```
public class QuizSchema {
    public static final class QuizTable{
        //nested class
        public static final String NAME = "quizTable";
        public static final class Cols{
            public static final String SCORE = "score";
            public static final String PARAGRAPH = "paragraph";
            public static final String FOREIGNID = "foreignId";
            public static final String UUID = "uuid";
            public static final String AVAILABLE = "available";
        }
    }
}
```

I am very confused because I can clearly see rows with `available` fields equal to 1 in my quiz table . Sorry for the broad question, it's just that I can't put a finger on a problem and the debugger isn't too helpful. Please let me know if you need more info.

[image]

Comment: Strangely enough I can return a query if I set the `available` field as a string that's not a number. Like "unavailable" instead of "0" and "available" for "1". Why do you think this is?

Comment: try `QuizCursorWrapper cursor = db.queryQuiz("CAST(" + QuizTable.Cols.AVAILABLE + " AS INTEGER) =CAST(? AS INTEGER)", new String[]{"1"});`

Comment: thank you, this worked when i represented numbers as strings and integers.

Comment: Good, I'll add an answer. Hopefully explaining why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that your issue is how column storage class/type affinity effects comparisons.

The solution is force the type affinity and thus how the comparisons are made. Forcing the type affinity can be achieved using **CAST** to set the type affinity.

As such a solution could be to **CAST** the values to type **INTEGER** for the comparison. You could do this by using :-

```
QuizCursorWrapper cursor = db.queryQuiz("CAST(" + QuizTable.Cols.AVAILABLE + " AS INTEGER) =CAST(? AS INTEGER)", new String[]{"1"});
```

You may wish to have a read of :-

[Datatypes In SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)